# How can I interact with this modal dialog using Webdriver & Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver, modal-dialog, lettuce

All I want is to close a modal dialog, ideally by doing the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("OK").click()
```

Gives `NoSuchElementException: Message: u'The element could not be found'` for the OK link text.

Same for the xpath when I do this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"modal\"]/div/div[2]/div/a").click()
```

I suspect this is because I need to put focus on the dialog. To do so I've tried:

```
for handle in browser.window_handles:
    browser.switch_to_window(handle)
    if browser.find_element_by_class_name('popUp123')
        browser.find_element_by_link_text("OK").click()
```

Gives `NoSuchElementException: Message: u'The element could not be found'` for the class.

Have also tried `browser.switch_to_frame(ID OR NAME)`, but couldn't find it as a frame either.

Please tell me I'm missing something blatantly obvious.

Relevant frame source (summarised):

```
<body id="modal">
    <div class="popUp123">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="centerbutton">
            <a href="#" class="close" onclick=parent.close">
                <span>OK</span>
```

Comment: If the error does not appear if you put a `time.sleep (2)` befor the code you may need to wait for the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code is using Java, u can try using the below code converting it to Python syntax. Sorry as I am Webdriver - Java Tester, I can't give you the Python code. Hope this will solve your requirements.

```
Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();
//Get the alert text
String alertText = alertDialog.getText();
//Click the OK button on the alert.
alertDialog.accept();
```

Cheers,

Mahesh

Answer (score 4):

This is the python syntax

```python
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

browser = WebDriver()

# do other stuff here

browser.switch_to_alert().accept()

# continue with other stuff here
```

The alert api is located in selenium.webdriver.common.alert